# NVIDIA RTX A6000でtensorflow-gpu 1.13.1が使えない

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

RTX A6000を使用しておりますが、下記の環境下（tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1）ではエラーが出てしまいます。
一方、tensorflow-gpuをバーション2.1にすると正常に動きます。
tensorflow-gpuバージョンを1.13.1で動かしたいのですが、RTX A6000では使用できないのでしょうか？

#### エラー内容、症状

- エラーメッセージにはメモリオーバーフローと記載（たぶん）
- エラーではないがGPUメモリのロードが異常に遅い

#### 確認内容

- 下記サイトのコードを動かして正常に動いているかの確認をしました。

  - tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1ではエラーメッセージでて止まります。
  - tensorflow-gpu 2.1ではエラーメッセージでずに正常に稼働。

  [TensorFlowのチュートリアルがディープラーニングの勉強のスタートに良かったのでオススメしたい](https://qiita.com/Kuma_T/items/4449f008cad18fbb7f1a)
- GPUやCUDAを認識しているかの動作確認は下記サイトを参考にしました。

  [NVIDIA CUDA toolkit on Windows](https://qiita.com/n-yamanaka/items/b00a94eec7eac4d2e76a)
  [TensorFlowでGPU学習させるためにCUDA周りではまったときの対処法](https://qiita.com/karaage0703/items/5d46b249f6be68186210)

#### エラーメッセージ

```
2021-06-17 13:47:01.520738: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:698] failed to run cuBLAS routine cublasSgemm_v2: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shibata-test.py", line 24, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
  File "C:\Users\ixs-quadro05\anaconda3\envs\deeplabv3plus\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 880, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\ixs-quadro05\anaconda3\envs\deeplabv3plus\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 329, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\ixs-quadro05\anaconda3\envs\deeplabv3plus\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3076, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\ixs-quadro05\anaconda3\envs\deeplabv3plus\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\ixs-quadro05\anaconda3\envs\deeplabv3plus\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(32, 512), b.shape=(512, 10), m=32, n=10, k=512
         [[{{node dense_1/MatMul}}]]
         [[{{node loss/mul}}]]
```

#### 環境

Windows : Windows 10 Pro, バージョン20H2
プロセッサ : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10980XE CPU @ 3.00GHz   3.00 GHz
NVIDIAドライバー : R460 U6 (462.31)
　ファイル名：462.31-quadro-rtx-desktop-notebook-win10-64bit-international-dch-whql.exe
NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit ：10.0
　ファイル名：：cuda_10.0.130_411.31_win10.exe
NVIDIA cuDNN：7.4
　ファイル名：cudnn-10.0-windows10-x64-v7.4.1.5.zip
Anaconda仮想環境内
・python : 3.6.8
・tensorflow-gpu : 1.13.1
　＊tensorflow-gpuをcondaでインストールするとcudnnなどが自動インストールされるためpipでインストール
　（上記でtensorflow-gpu 2.1に変更すると動く！！）

**補足**

- tensorflow-gpuバージョンを下記に変更しても動きませんでした
  1.13.1、1.14.0、1.15.0、2.0.0
- CUDAなどバージョンを下記に変更しても動きません。ただ、tensorflow-gpu 2.1は動きます。
  CUDA Toolkit ：10.1、cuDNN：7.6
- NVIDIAに問い合わせましたが「tensorflowはオープンソースソフトウェアのため回答できません」とのことです

Comment: 具体的にどのようなエラーが表示されたのかも質問に含めておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーなど追記しました。